# Selecting records from a table not in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

```
Course
course_id | name
------------------
1         | PROG
2         | ENGL
3         | SCIE

Enrollment List
ID | student_id | course_id | grade
-----------------------------------
1  | 445566     | 1         | 4.0
2  | 445566     | 2         | 2.0
3  | 778899     | 3         | 2.5
```

I need to query the tables such that it returns the student_id and the courses they haven't taken yet. Outcome should be:

```
student_id | course_id
----------------------
445566     | 3
778899     | 1
778899     | 2
```

I tried the query

```
SELECT student_id, name FROM course c, list l WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM course c, list l WHERE c.course_id=l.course_id)
```

which returned zero records. How would I do this?

Comment: you get a cross product. learn about join

Comment: left joins and check for null

Comment: What is 'grade' in this context? Is that like 'level'/'difficulty'?

Comment: Grade as in grading, the teacher's evaluation of a student. Thank you for the recommendations. I have a lot to learn about joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

In any case, you need to approach this in a particular way.  Start with a list of all students and all courses.  Then use `left join` or `not exists` to filter out the ones that are not in the list:

```
SELECT s.student_id, c.name
FROM course c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT student_id FROM list l) s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM list l2
                  WHERE c.course_id = l2.course_id and s.student_id = l2.student_id
                 )
```